# android studio error building app not installed as package appears to be invalid

Tags: android

I am trying to build a simple app using android studio but whenever I click build APK I get this message:

```
  Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

I found the solution to build the APK which is adding below code to build gradle,

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

but the problem is when I try to install the app in the phone I get this error message

```
 app not installed as package appears to be invalid
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Invoke-custom` is a Dalvik byte code command. Most likely one of the libraries you have included has been compiled for a newer Android version but does not contain a correct minSDK configuration. If it is a pre-compiled library you only have the choice to remove the library or increase the minSDK configuration of your app.

Comment: See also this other unresolved thread on Android StackExchange: [Sharing APK of app I made myself to my other phone tells me "App not installed as package appears to be invalid"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252577)

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you try to install an app from someone's Android phone running on version 10 or above.
some metadata and Android files are not included inside the package.
Let me know if you are sending the APK by simply sharing the app from your phone, or the APK file you created from android studio.

Comment: I created APK file from android studio and send it by usb

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as the OP. In my case built it to my dev phone where it worked, then shared it via BlueTooth to my daily phone, where I get the "appears to be invalid" error when I try to install the APK. Do you know which metadata in particular I need to modify?

Answer (score 1):

**Just clean your project & build again. It worked for me.**

[image]